# Swift - String to date - type "12/29/14, 9:24 AM"

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsdate

I've tried to find the format to convert this type of date-string to date. I'm assuming you can use this method to convert it:

```
var dateString = "2014-07-15" // change to your date format

var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"

var date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)
println(date)
```

and just replace the dateFormat, but I can't find the format.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

EDIT: To be clear, I need to convert a string "12/29/14, 9:24 AM", and not the one that's written in the code. I also need the time, if that's an extra effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want 12/29/14 9:24 AM then `dd/MM/YY h:mm a` This how you format .
and if you have 12/29/14 09:24 AM `dd/MM/YY hh:mm a`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a good writeup about the formats you can use instead of `YYYY-MM-DD`

http://waracle.net/iphone-nsdateformatter-date-formatting-table/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd"
d-meanes date in month 
D-meanes date in year.
Edit 
I tried (in playground) the code you posted and works!
Image(I don't have reputation):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSClJ.png
Edit nr 2
It is better to formatted like this `"YYYY-MM-dd-HH"`;`"2014-07-15-21"` and `println(date)`gave me. 
Thanks now I unwrap it but  gave me the 14 , a couple of hours back.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EecX6.png

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking your code is correct. Except the fact that you did not unwrap your optional

```
var dateString = "2014-07-15" // change to your date format
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd"

if let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString) {
    date //"Jan 15, 2014, 12:00 AM"
    println(date)
}
```

Note that `dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateString)` give you an optional because the string you pass in may not be a date string. in that case it will return nil. For example:

```
if let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString("6666-77-99") {
   println(date) // no output
} else {
  println("Error message") // "Error message"
}
```

Comment: I guess it was not clear enough what I was asking: I know the code I wrote was right, but I need to convert a string on the form "12/29/14 9:24 AM" instead of the one in the code. Sorry for the misunderstanding.